# Dimension via Sobolev spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, fractional-sobolev-spaces

For a non-empty compact subset $K\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and $s\in\mathbb{R}$ denote $H^s_K$ the set of Sobolev-functions of order $s$ which are supported in $K$. Define
$$\delta(K)= \inf \{\epsilon\ge0: H^{-\epsilon}_K \neq 0 \} \in [ 0, d/2].$$
When $K$ has positive ($d$-dimensional) Lebesgue measure, then obviously $\delta(K)=0$. Further, if $K$ is a subset of an $m$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and has positive ($m$-dimensional) Lebesgue measure, then 
 $\delta(K)=(d-m)/2$. This suggests to view the quantity
$$
\dim_S K := d - 2 \delta(K)\in [ 0, d]
$$
as a dimension of some sort.

**Question:** Has this notion been studied anywhere, in particular is it known whether $\dim_S$ coincides with some other notion of dimension, e.g. the Hausdorff dimension, especially when taking non-integer values?

Comment: How do you define $H_K^{-\varepsilon}$? Are these elements of the dual of $H^\varepsilon(\mathbb R^d)$ which are "supported" (how to define this precisely?) in $K$?

Comment: Here is a wild guess: maybe your 'Sobolev dimension' is related to the notion of capacity. I would conjecture that $H_K^{-\varepsilon} \ne \emptyset$ if and only if the $\varepsilon$-capacity of $K$ is non-zero. There are also relations between the Hausdorff dimension and non-zero capacity (one should find this in the book by Adams&Hedberg). At the end, it might be possible that the Sobolev dimension coincides with the Hausdorff dimension.

Comment: I view $H_K^s$ as a subset of the distributions $\mathscr{D}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and use the same notion of support. In particular a distribution $u$ lies in $H_K^s$, if (a) $\langle u, \varphi\rangle = 0$ for every test function $\varphi$ with support disjoint from $K$ and if (b) the Fourier transform $\hat u $ lies in the  $L^2$-space with measure $(1+\vert \xi \vert^2)^s d \xi$.

Comment: And thanks for the suggestion I will check in how far this relates to capacity!